# Escaping out of the Find and Replace box in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

I'm in Visual Studio 2008, and I'm editing a CSS file.  I use ctrl+f a lot to find stuff around the file.  Once I find something, I'm used to using the Esc key get out of the find window and back into the editor.

I'd swear this is how it works when I'm at the office, but at home, I have to hit ctrl+tab to get back to the editor window and I hate it!  Anyone know what's going on here, or if I'm just going crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my Esc key is just plain broken.  LOL

Answer (score 1):

Certain windows in VS can be set as Floating, Dockable, Tabbed, etc. Try changing it to one of the other ones and see if it helps (right click the title of the search window).